# How can I change the cursor when dragging? Material CDK Drag and Drop

Tags: css, drag-and-drop, angular-material

Using the Drag and Drop behavior from the Material CDK library, I'm trying to change the cursor upon dragging a `cdkDrag` element.

For example, in [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8kjj3) the cursor is `grab` upon hover. I'd like it to change to `grabbing` upon drag. An example of this is what happens when grabbing a row in Google Sheets:

[image]

Reading [the documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#styling) for styling a drag and drop component, it looks like adding a cursor property to this class should do the trick:

> .cdk-drop-list-dragging: A class that is added to cdkDropList while the user is dragging an item.

The code looks like this:

```
.example-box {
  /* other CSS properties */
  cursor: grab;
}

.cdk-drop-list-dragging {
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

However, as you can see in the StackBlitz, that doesn't seem to change the cursor. I'm guessing this is because this class applies to the list and not the cursor.

Another potential was the `.cdk-drag-preview` class:

> .cdk-drag-preview: This is the element that will be rendered next to the user's cursor as they're dragging an item in a sortable list. By default the element looks exactly like the element that is being dragged.

This doesn't seem to work either. I think it's because it changes the element rendered next to the cursor and not the cursor itself.

Any ideas on how to get the cursor to change while dragging?

Comment: The previous solutions did not work for me, but [here is something that will most likely work for anyone still having issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65774866/9356733)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `cursor: grabbing` to your `example-box:active`

```
.example-box:active {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
              0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
              0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

---

> The :active selector is used to select and style the active link.
>
> A link becomes active when you click on it.
>
> **Tip:** The :active selector can be used on all elements, not only links.

Additional information here

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

---

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8kjj3-r993mc?embed=1&file=app/cdk-drag-drop-overview-example.css

Comment: Could you add to your answer what `active` does here and how you knew to use that property? I ask because I didn't see any explanations in the documentation and I'd love to learn not just the answer but also the why behind it.

Comment: @Marshal any idea how to make this work for a cdkDropList?  This example does not work.

Comment: I didn't downvote but you may want to add details that this answer is related to a CSS pseudo class for when we click and hold on any element. It's not Angular specific.

Answer (score 14):

The previous solutions did not work for me, but here is something that will most likely work for anyone still having issues:

first add this global CSS:

```
body.inheritCursors * {
  cursor: inherit !important;
}
```

and to your cdkDrag element add cdkDragStarted and attach it to a method in your .ts file:

```
<div cdkDrag (cdkDragStarted)="dragStart($event)"></div>
```

In your .ts file you can then toggle the cursor you want when a drag starts and stops:

```
bodyElement: HTMLElement = document.body;

  dragStart(event: CdkDragStart) {
    this.bodyElement.classList.add('inheritCursors');
    this.bodyElement.style.cursor = 'move'; 
    //replace 'move' with what ever type of cursor you want
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    this.bodyElement.classList.remove('inheritCursors');
    this.bodyElement.style.cursor = 'unset';
    ...
    ...
  }
```

Here is a link to a working [example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5u1bm?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts)

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: The marked answer works for the OP's sample. This answer however works in a more general sense and specifically when working with a `cdkDropList`.

Comment: True, I believe this is a good option for people who are struggling with similar obstacles to OP's and find them selves here in their search of a solution - In my case I had multiple `cdkDropList`'s that I connected. I wasn't getting the desired grabbing cursor I wanted when dragging a `cdkDrag` element out of its origin parent element.

Answer (score 1):

For myself, I added the following style override to re-enable the custom cursor while dragging.

```
.draggable-element .drag-handle{
  cursor: grab;
}

.draggable-element.cdk-drag-preview .drag-handle{
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

Link to [live Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2yu5w?file=src/app/cdk-drag-drop-custom-placeholder-example.css)

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks for the contribution. Unfortunately this solution doesn't replicate the grabbing behavior on click like the accepted answer (since it grabs only on drag).

Answer (score 1):

If we have this example

```html
    <div cdkDropList class="drag-drop-container">
      <div *ngFor="let item of array" cdkDrag>
        // content
      </div>
    </div>
```

use .cdk-drop-list-dragging

```css
.drag-drop-container.cdk-drop-list-dragging {
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

you might need to add this to other classes as well

Answer (score 0):

In your linked Stackblitz example, you're not using a droplist, so you'd want your css to be:

```
.cdk-drag-dragging {
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

In my case, drag-dropping using a list on a table-body element, I used:

```
table tbody.cdk-drop-list-dragging td {
  cursor: grabbing !important;
}
```

Comment: The accepted answer uses the linked stackblitz referenced by the OP to provide a solution to the question.

Comment: It is true, that the accepted answer is not enough when using droplist. It will lose the style as soon as you start moving around the element. But also this answer is not quite complete, because it will miss the grabbing at the start (before starting moving). To make it fully work, I had to combine this answer and the accepted one.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `onmousedown = "changeCursorPoint()"` event function -

```
private changeCursorPoint(): void {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'grabbing';
}
```

Clear the function again on `(cdkDropListDropped) = "clearCursorEvent()"`

```
private changeCursorToDefault(): void {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
 }
```