# Keep cursor grabbing between list. @angluar/cdk/drag-drop

Tags: css, angular

I have [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xnq7vh) in stackblitz. I use `@angular/cdk/drag-drop` in my project. I try to change the cursor to `cursor:grabb` and `cursor:grabbing` when the cursor is up an element and when I drag a picked element.

I use this line:

```css
.example-box:active {
  cursor:grabbing
}
```

But its not working. What's I need to do?

Comment: It's already linked, but I think it duplicates this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53674488/how-can-i-change-the-cursor-when-dragging-material-cdk-drag-and-drop

Answer (score 2):

I know it's has been a while, but I found a solution to the issue!

first add this global CSS:

```
body.inheritCursors * {
  cursor: inherit !important;
}
```

and to your cdkDrag element add cdkDragStarted and attach it to a method in your .ts file:

```
<div cdkDrag (cdkDragStarted)="dragStart($event)"></div>
```

In you .ts file you can then toggle the cursor you want when a drag starts and stops:

```
bodyElement: HTMLElement = document.body;

  dragStart(event: CdkDragStart) {
    this.bodyElement.classList.add('inheritCursors');
    this.bodyElement.style.cursor = 'move'; 
    //replace 'move' with what ever type of cursor you want
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    this.bodyElement.classList.remove('inheritCursors');
    this.bodyElement.style.cursor = 'unset';
    ...
    ...
  }
```

Here is a link to a working [example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5u1bm?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts)

Hope this helps ‍

Answer (score 1):

CDK adds the class `cdk-drop-list-dragging` to the parent element with the `cdkDropList` directive on it while dragging.  So adding the following CSS works for my situation where I do not allow the element to move outside of the container

```
.cdk-drop-list-dragging {
  cursor: move;
}
```